# mixing percent and px in css without using calc()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a resizable `<ul>` with 2 `<li>` elements, a header and content. The header should stay at a fixed `height: 35px;`, no matter what happens to the rest of the elements. I would like the content to take up the rest of the `<ul>`. The problem is it can never fill the rest, because it grows at its own rate, so there is a small margin of the `<ul>` at the bottom. I could fix this with `height: calc(100% - 35px);` but there is so little that supports `calc`. Is there a way to do this with out calc?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/k4E5F/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/k4E5F/1/)

**No `calc` needed!**

Simply set the `postion` of the parent container to `relative` then the children to `absolute`, anchoring the content with a `bottom` of zero and `top` of 35 (the height of the header).

CSS

```
.resize_container {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 65% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
.container_t {
    list-style: none;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}
.header_t {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:absolute;
}
.content_container_t {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    bottom:0;
}
.ui-resizable-n {
    cursor: n-resize;
    border-top: 5px solid purple;
}
ui-resizable-e {
    cursor: e-resize;
    border-right: 5px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: But would this work if I added content inside of the content_container like a textarea that or buttons?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled - this should work absolutely fine, you can always add `overflow:auto` to `.content_container_t` in order to ensure correct space allocations.

Comment: Unfortunatly its not perfect, I tried adding a textarea with a height and width of 90% to the content_container_t in your example, and the textarea ended up suffering from the same problem as I stared with. I was able to fix it with '.content_t { position:absolute; width: 90%; left: 5px; top: 5px; bottom: 5px; }' but can you think of a cleaner way?

Comment: See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/k4E5F/4/ This is a question of CSS styling, you may need to open another question for the specifics of what you're trying to do next to ensure it gets maximum visibility by the community

Comment: Any idea with my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386171/how-to-ensure-the-background-image-inside-a-div-is-evenly-shown/26386885?noredirect=1#comment41429223_26386885

Answer (score 2):

You can use crosse-browser calc like this

```
.foo {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 35px); //Chrome
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 35px); //firefox
  width: calc(100% - 35px); //IE
}
```

or with JQuery:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("foo").style.width= window.innerWidth - 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
.content_container_t {
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LBgbw/)